# Como guardar informacion en planilla de ingreso de datos de Google Sheets, en una hoja de calculo en otra carpeta en Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo este codigo, muy sencillo, hecho en apps scripts, donde doy los parametros para que se guarde la informacion ingresada en una hoja de calculo del mismo archivo.

a modo de ejemplo, dejo una parte del codigo que necesito modificar:

```
// Guardar celdas
function Guardar(){
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Ingreso"); // Nombre de hoja del formulario
  var datos = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Prueba"); // Nombre de hoja donde se almacenan datos
  
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("C3").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("L5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("L8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C11").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F11").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I11").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("L11").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C14").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F14").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("I14").getValue()]];

 // Inyección de datos a hoja donde se almacenan datos
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,16).setValues(valores); // El "6" se cambia por cantidad de datos a almacenar

  Limpiar(); // Ejecución de función para limpieza de celdas
}
```

Mi problema es que ahora deberia guardar la informacion que igreso, en un archivo independiente a este, ubicado en otra carpeta. Me esta costando mucho escribir el codigo, ya que soy bastante nuevo en esta herramienta. Podrian darme una mano?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Para escribir datos en otra hoja de cálculo primero debes objetener un objeto tipo Class Spreadsheet. Existen varios métodos para esto, SpreadsheetApp.openByIdm, SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl, SpreadsheetApp.open. Ver https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app. Si necesitas mayor orientación muestra lo que haz intentado y agrega una breve descripción de tus esfuerzos de búsqueda como se sugiere en [ask].

Comment: Ruben, muchas gracias por contestar.
Evidentemente, la pregunta no estaba como lo sugiere Como preguntar. Lo voy a tener en cuenta para la proxima consulta. Pero, con esta informacion que me pasaste, ya fui capaz de resolver mi problema.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En la parte inferior de la pregunta, dice "Tu Respuesta", agrega los pasos que realizaste para resolver tu escenario, de este modo podrás ser el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo escenario o uno muy similar, luego espera 24 horas para marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, de ese modo ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paso a dar la respuesta a mi problema:

```
function Guardar(){
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Ingreso"); // Nombre de hoja del formulario
  var hojaDestino = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CuP5yRxKrhubZbkb9KrTSJFn5OqyTPzbDi2ixKwJEpY')
  var datos = hojaDestino.getSheetByName("4.FCVentas"); // Nombre de hoja donde se almacenan datos
  
  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("C3").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C4").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C7").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C9").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C10").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F3").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F4").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F7").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F9").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F10").getValue()]];

 // Inyección de datos a hoja donde se almacenan datos
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,2,1,16).setValues(valores);
```

Para poder guardar lo ingresado en otro Sheet, lo que hice fue crea una nueva variable (hojaDestino), y agregarle el metodo Openbyid, como bien me comento Ruben. La linea de codigo puntualmente queda asi:

```
var hojaDestino = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CuP5yRxKrhubZbkb9KrTSJFn5OqyTPzbDi2ixKwJEpY')
```

El id se encuentra dentro del URL del sheet en cuestion. Paso a dejar nuevamente la documentacion para mas informacion.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Por ultimo paso en otra linea, la hoja de destino donde deben quedar impresos los datos:

```
var datos = hojaDestino.getSheetByName("4.FCVentas");
```

Gracias fredyfx por avisar que es lo que debia hacer. Voy a estar mas atento a las normas para la proxima.

Comment: Un placer colaborar con el sitio y con los usuarios, en especial cuando la gente entiende las sugerencias y recomendaciones sin incomodarse puesto que van en buen plan :D ¡Que sigan los éxitos estimado! #ConTodoElPower2.0!!! Saludos.